# Do magical recordings exist in the wizarding world?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

In Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince: A Very Frosty Christmas, there is a scene where they have the radio on. Celestina is singing this famous song "A Cauldron Full of Hot, Strong Love", which Molly loves but Fleur Delacour hates.

I was wondering if that was recorded, or if Celestina Warbeck is singing live. If it is recorded, is it known how wizards do that, and how they save the recording?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115211/do-witches-and-wizards-play-vinyl-records

Comment: they have magical cameras, it stands to reason there would be audio. One type of recording is the glasses Harry has at the QWC that allows him to slow down and replay events

Answer (score 0):

It is not known how Wizards record music. They do have their own form of radio, so that is a possible medium. I am willing to guess that they can magically record their music, but again, there is no evidence of that statement, but it would logically make sense.